# Scala/Hadoop: Specifying Context for Reducer

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce

Before I jump into playing with Scoobi or Scrunch, I thought I'd try to port WordCount to scala (2.9.1) using just Hadoop (0.20.1)'s java bindings.

Originally, I had:

```
class Map extends Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable] {
  @throws[classOf[IOException]]
  @throws[classOf[InterruptedException]]
  def map(key : LongWritable, value : Text, context : Context) {
    //...
```

Which compiled fine, but gave me a runtime error:

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

After looking around a bit, I figured out that it was because I wasn't defining the proper `map` method (should have been cued off by the lack of `override`), so I fixed it to be:

```
override def map(key : LongWritable, value : Text, 
  context : Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable]#Context) {
```

And voila, no runtime error.

But then I looked at the job output, and realized that my reducer wasn't getting run.

So I looked at my reducer, and noticed the `reduce` signature had the same problem as my mapper:

```
class Reduce extends Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable] {
  @throws[classOf[IOException]]
  @throws[classOf[InterruptedException]]
  def reduce(key : Text, value : Iterable[IntWritable], context : Context) {
    //...
```

So I guessed the identity `reduce` was being used because of the mismatch.

But when I attempted to correct the signature of `reduce`:

```
override def reduce(key: Text, values : Iterable[IntWritable], 
  context : Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable]#Context) {
```

I now got a compiler error:

```
[ERROR] /path/to/src/main/scala/WordCount.scala:32: error: method reduce overrides nothing
[INFO]     override def reduce(key: Text, values : Iterable[IntWritable],
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: And what's the reduce signature supposed to be?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: That's my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first glance, make sure that values is java.lang.Iterable, not scala Iterable. Either import java.lang.Iterable, or:

```
override def reduce(key: Text, values : java.lang.Iterable[IntWritable], context : Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable]#Context)
```

Comment: this is exactly right.  see here for an example: https://bitbucket.org/jasonbaldridge/fogbow/src/6c24fb2afda4/src/main/scala/fogbow/example/WordCount.scala